# Can we import .apparchive bundles in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, ios, archive

In Xcode 3, applications were archived in .apparchive folders.

In Xcode 4, applications are now archived in an .xcarchive bundle.

Is there a way to convert .apparchive folders in .xcarchive bundles or to open .apparchive folders with Xcode 4?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dave Dunkin's script worked great, but I missed the icon and version in some cases. Below a slightly adjusted version of the script. <s>You need to install MacRuby, available here: http://www.macruby.org/downloads.html.</s>

```
#!/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/A/usr/bin/macrub‌​y

framework 'Cocoa'
require 'date'
require 'fileutils'

Dir.glob(Dir.home() + '/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Archived Applications/*.apparchive').each { |apparchivePath|

  print "Found archive at #{apparchivePath}... "

  archiveInfo = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithContentsOfURL(NSURL.fileURLWithPath(apparchivePath + '/ArchiveInfo.plist')) 

  name = archiveInfo['XCUserProvidedName'] || archiveInfo['XCApplicationName']
  appFilename = archiveInfo['XCApplicationFilename']
  appPath = 'Applications/' + appFilename
  archiveDate = archiveInfo['XCArchivedDate']
  xcarchivePath = Dir.home() + '/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/' + archiveDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '/' + name + ' ' + archiveDate.strftime('%m-%d-%y %I.%M %p') + '.xcarchive'
  appVersion = archiveInfo['CFBundleVersion']
  iconPaths = archiveInfo['XCInfoPlist']['CFBundleIconFiles']
  if not iconPaths
    iconPaths = appPath + '/' + archiveInfo['XCInfoPlist']['CFBundleIconFile']
  else
    iconPaths = archiveInfo['XCInfoPlist']['CFBundleIconFiles'].collect { |f| appPath + '/' + f }
  end

  if File.directory?(xcarchivePath)
    puts 'skipping'
  else
    puts 'importing'
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(xcarchivePath)

    xcarchiveInfo = {
      'ApplicationProperties' => {
        'ApplicationPath' => appPath,
        'CFBundleIdentifier' => archiveInfo['CFBundleIdentifier'],
        'CFBundleShortVersionString' => appVersion,
        'IconPaths' => iconPaths
      },
      'ArchiveVersion' => 1,
      'CreationDate' => archiveDate,
      'Name' => name,
      'SchemeName' => archiveInfo['XCApplicationName']
    }
    if archiveInfo.has_key?('XCUserProvidedComment')
      xcarchiveInfo['Comment'] = archiveInfo['XCUserProvidedComment']
    end
    xcarchiveInfo.writeToURL(NSURL.fileURLWithPath(xcarchivePath + '/Info.plist'), atomically:false)

    FileUtils.mkdir_p(xcarchivePath + '/Products/Applications')
    FileUtils.cp_r(apparchivePath + '/' + appFilename, xcarchivePath + '/Products/Applications')
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(xcarchivePath + '/dSYMs')
    FileUtils.cp_r(apparchivePath + '/' + appFilename + '.dSYM', xcarchivePath + '/dSYMs')
  end
}
```

Comment: The CFBundleIconFile modification is a good idea, but it doesn't work as presented. IconPaths needs to be an array, not a string.

Comment: FWIW, you can get this script to work on Lion without installing anything by changing the first line to "#!/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/A/usr/bin/macruby" (excluding the outer quotation marks).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a MacRuby script I wrote to do this for me.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/macruby

framework 'Cocoa'
require 'date'
require 'fileutils'

Dir.glob(Dir.home() + '/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Archived Applications/*.apparchive').each { |apparchivePath|

  print "Found archive at #{apparchivePath}... "

  archiveInfo = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithContentsOfURL(NSURL.fileURLWithPath(apparchivePath + '/ArchiveInfo.plist')) 

  name = archiveInfo['XCUserProvidedName'] || archiveInfo['XCApplicationName']
  appFilename = archiveInfo['XCApplicationFilename']
  appPath = 'Applications/' + appFilename
  archiveDate = archiveInfo['XCArchivedDate']
  xcarchivePath = Dir.home() + '/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/' + archiveDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '/' + name + ' ' + archiveDate.strftime('%m-%d-%y %I.%M %p') + '.xcarchive'

  if File.directory?(xcarchivePath)
    puts 'skipping'
  else
    puts 'importing'
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(xcarchivePath)

    xcarchiveInfo = {
      'ApplicationProperties' => {
        'ApplicationPath' => appPath,
        'CFBundleIdentifier' => archiveInfo['CFBundleIdentifier'],
        'IconPaths' => archiveInfo['XCInfoPlist']['CFBundleIconFiles'].collect { |f| appPath + '/' + f }
      },
      'ArchiveVersion' => 1,
      'CreationDate' => archiveDate,
      'Name' => name,
      'SchemeName' => archiveInfo['XCApplicationName']
    }
    if archiveInfo.has_key?('XCUserProvidedComment')
      xcarchiveInfo['Comment'] = archiveInfo['XCUserProvidedComment']
    end
    xcarchiveInfo.writeToURL(NSURL.fileURLWithPath(xcarchivePath + '/Info.plist'), atomically:false)

    FileUtils.mkdir_p(xcarchivePath + '/Products/Applications')
    FileUtils.cp_r(apparchivePath + '/' + appFilename, xcarchivePath + '/Products/Applications')
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(xcarchivePath + '/dSYMs')
    FileUtils.cp_r(apparchivePath + '/' + appFilename + '.dSYM', xcarchivePath + '/dSYMs')
  end
}
```

Comment: could you tell us how to use it? I get "conv.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kDO_BLOCK"

Comment: ok by deleting "atomically:" I get an error on line 3 "framework"

Comment: finally got it to work (I even don't know how) but have to do a lot of work on my own. In fact in older archives the date was saved as float and so on.

Comment: The script requires MacRuby. I used version 0.9, don't know if it'll work on earlier versions. @iPortable, it sounds like you're not using MacRuby or using an old version.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I've made some minor adjustments to your script to import version number as well (see my answer). (And import icon when it was in CFBundleIconFile instead of CFBundleIconFiles.)

Comment: Installed MacRuby 0.9 and the script ran successfully. I still couldn't symbolicate a crash log from one of my users though :(

Answer (score 3):

I just did one by hand, so it's definitely possible, but tedious for more than one or two. With a bit of time, someone could write a script to do this.

`.xcarchive` bundles are just directories, like `.apparchive` bundles before them. The newer format moved some things around and simplified the top level `Info.plist`.

Xcode 3 stores the archives in `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Archived Applications`. Individual archive bundles are named as a GUID. Inside each is the `ArchiveInfo.plist`, the actual `.app` bundle and the `.dSYM` bundle.

Xcode 4 stores the archives in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives`, separated into folders named after the date the archive is created. Within each date folder is the `.xcarchive` bundle, using a readable name instead of a GUID. Within that is the `Info.plist`, a `Products` folder where the `.app` lives, and a `dSYMs` folder to hold the `.dSYM` bundles.

A quick-and-dirty way to copy a `.apparchive` to a `.xcarchive`:

1. Create a new folder with the date when the archive was created.
2. Copy the contents of the `.apparchive` into a new folder ending with `.xcarchive` inside that new folder.
3. `cd` into that new `.xcarchive` folder. Everything is relative to that from this point forward.
4. Create `Products` and `dSYMs` folders.
5. Move your `.app` bundle into `Products`.
6. Move your `.dSYM` bundle into `dSYMs`.
7. Remove the old `ArchiveInfo.plist` file.
8. Create a new `Info.plist` that looks like this, substituting as appropriate.

(ending the list so StackOverflow formats the XML properly...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ApplicationProperties</key>
    <dict>
        <key>ApplicationPath</key>
        <string>AppBundleName.app</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.example.app-id</string>
        <key>IconPaths</key>
        <array>
            <string>AppBundleName.app/Icon.png</string>
            <string>AppBundleName.app/Icon-Small.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>ArchiveVersion</key>
    <real>1</real>
    <key>CreationDate</key>
    <date>2010-12-15T15:10:34Z</date> <!-- this is a GMT time stamp -->
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>AppName</string>
    <key>SchemeName</key>
    <string>AppName</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```